Remapping Keyboard From MacOS to Windows 11
I put together a GMMK-RGB Glorius keyboard a while back and used it with my macbook. Because the keyboard has a typical Windows layout, I remapped some of the keys (like switching the Option and Command Keys) so it would work nicely with MacOS.
Now I would like to use the keyboard with a PC running Windows 11 but neither Windows key on my remapped keyboard seems to do anything. I have tried plugging the keyboard back into my mac and resetting all of the key defaults and disabling gaming mode on windows 11 but neither seems to fix the problem.
Any ideas how to fix the issue?

I use an actual physical macOS keyboard with a USB switcher to switch it between my Mac and my PC. On the PC side, I use an old piece of software called keytweak. You can find it from various download sites, but I don’t really trust most of them. If you find a reputable download site for that app, go ahead and use it, it’s terrific. But Microsoft themselves appear to have a newer tool that I have not tried yet, part of their power tools. See https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/
